# How do I work around not being able to call a controller method from a controller's class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with a Rails controller that has two methods:

```rb
...

protected
  def self.some_method
    ...
    another_method
    ...
  end

  def another_method
    ...
  end
```

I want to be able to call `another_method` from `self.some_method`. Unfortunately, I get:

```
undefined method `another_method' for MyNamespace::MyController:Class
```

I assume this has to do with one method being a class method. My goal here is to avoid code duplication, because I need to use `another_method` in regular controller actions, as well.

Is there a better place I could put `another_method` so it's available to both `self.some_method` and to regular controller actions? It needs to be in a controller because I need access to `current_user`.

Comment: `another_method` is being called from an instance of the controller, rather than from the controller class itself, because the controller is not instantiated, you cant call the instance method. Something like the `new` method in `User.new` is a class method, but when you hit the `index` route of your `UsersController`, this is an instance method on an instance of `UserController`. Can you provide some more context about what `self.some_method` is doing here? Unsure why you would need to (or want to) add class methods to a controller.

Comment: Reiterating the above, `self.some_method` is ringing alarm bells for me. Why are you defining a class method in a controller? I strongly suspect that this code either belongs *somewhere else entirely*, or it should be an instance method. Perhaps you could be using a **module** to include shared methods between multiple controllers? Or perhaps that could be some sort of **service object**?

Comment: @bashford7 Thank you for the insight, this totally makes sense. I completely agree about the controller class method, I think it's bad practice. Unfortunately it was written by more senior engineer and is involved in some tightly-bound monkey-patching business, and I can't get rid of it without extensive refactoring. If you'd like you can provide your helpful explanation and suggestion to refactor out the class method, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @TomLord I agree that the class method is bad practice and something else should have been done, but I can't do anything about that now, as per my other comment to bashford7 ^.

Comment: @DavidGay *"but I can't do anything about that now"* why not? Where/how is the class method used? Are you not able to update the usages to make use of the instance method instead? The problem is that controller class methods do not have access to the incoming request. So you will not have access to `current_user`. You can pass `current_user` through the arguments when calling `some_method`. This would require you to call the method either from a controller instance, the view, or a view helper (everywhere where you do have access to `current_user`).

Comment: I didnt't know class methods at controller level could be something. Actually I am wondering how you call it. You may not be able to reveal what it contains but maybe you can explain where `self.some_method` is called ..

Comment: @DavidGay if you could provide the full controller, or at least the important parts, we should be able to find a way to achieve what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reasonably provide the controller nor the class method here, because I can't provide them in full and I wouldn't know how to simplify the class method. It's a monstrosity and I don't have time to pick it apart and try to understand how it works. Basically from this question I just wanted to understand why I couldn't call an controller method from a controller class method, and how to work around it, and that's been explained well enough. The answer is to put the code somewhere else, because you can't call an instance method from a class method. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to call `another_method` from the class method, then you can't have any instance state available in it. Therefore you can define it as class method too, or put it in an entirely different place (like a util function module:

```
module Utils
  module_function

  def another_method
    ...
  end
end


class MyController
  def self.some_method
    ...
    Utils.another_method
    ...
  end
end
```

I can see how the `some_method` might have ended up there, it is overriding some of the Rails's own class methods. But again, you won't have any instance state in it, so if you need to have a different behavior per instance (for instance accessing the request) you are out of luck, you need to find another way.